# Inheriting Maven profiles and activation

Tags: java, maven

My maven project defines a profile with activation condition and has a child module. The activation condition of the parent project is ignored and I have to copy it to the child.

Parent:

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>container</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                    <value>local</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Child:

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>

            <!-- Remove comments and it will work: -->
            <!--
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                    <value>local</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            -->

            <dependencies>
                <!-- (...) --->
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Then I run

```
mvn package -Dspring.profiles.active=local -P !container
```

and the dependecies of profile "local" are missing in the artifacts. If I remove the comments around the activation, the dependencies are available. The result equal when I run `mvn package` from the parent and from the child project's directory.

Strange thing is that `help:active-profiles` says the profile is avaiable if the activation is commented out in the child, as expected:

```
C:\myproject> cd child
C:\myproject\child> mvn help:active-profiles -Dspring.profiles.active=local -P !container

(...)

The following profiles are active:

 - local (source: org.example:myproject:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT)
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: What does the effective POM say? I guess that profiles cannot be "amended" in the way you try to do it.

Comment: The effective POM contains the local profile section with its dependecies as defined in in the child pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that profiles are not merged with the one in the parent, but that a profile with the same name completely overrides the profile from the parent.

So your construction will probably not work.

Comment: Then why does `help:active-profiles` list it as active? If it's really active then even if it's overridden that would be fine, because the deps are defined in the child.